# Action to be performed before uninstalling windows metro app

Tags: passwords, windows-store-apps, uninstallation, passwordvault

I want to execute some code when metro app is uninstalled .
Basically I want to remove the credentials saved with password vault before the app is uninstalled . I just want to eecute 2-3 lines of code before the app is uninstalled .
Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>`PasswordVault` will remove credentials when app is uninstalled. No need to do that manually.</s>

Maybe you have to remove it by yourself. Check out the below given MSDN threads.

[How to remove credentials in password vault when user uninstall the app?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/e2705768-fdc5-4143-a4e8-e861678b14c1/how-to-remove-credentials-in-password-vault-when-user-uninstall-the-app?forum=winappswithcsharp)

[Password Vault security](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/0085fdae-9f5e-49ca-a7b3-64333248e530/password-vault-security?forum=winappswithcsharp)

Comment: But after uninstalling the app, the credentials were still present in the credential manager.I had to manually remove them so that after re-installing the app , it shouldn't login automatically